# How to pass c++ object pointer back when making a node add-on

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I'm making a Node add-on to expose some functions from `libmpg123` to Javascript. Specifically I need to somehow pass back a pointer to a `out123_handle` object to javascript, which is produced from [out123_new](https://www.mpg123.de/api/group__out123__api.shtml#ga4b237e5ac68539a15c438d4d2038e1b9). The examples do not mention passing back a pointer anywhere. I'm a complete newbie to C++ as well as Node add-on so please be gentle. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: curious about this, did you find an answer?

Comment: Sorry, this has been so long ago that I no longer remember what I did.